# How to find Number object inside type

Tags: javascript, numbers

Number object in javascript accept all type of numbers like integer,float,hexadecimal,etc.

How to find number object inside type of number? like that number integer or hexa decimal

```js
var num = new Number(23.456);
console.log(typeof(num)) //output:object
```

but i want to see number of value type

how to find?

Comment: Why are you using `new Number()` in the first place?

Comment: JavaScript does not have integers, floats, hexadecimals, etc. It only supports IEEE 754 floating point numbers for the base number type. The `Number` object wrapper also uses the same. These accept different representations as literals, e.g., `0xFF` but that isn't a hex number - it's still converted to a IEEE 754 float in memory. There is no record kept how a given number was created, nor any formatting attached. `0xFF` is exactly the same number as `255` and exactly the same as `255.0` and exactly the same as `0b11111111`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `valueOf()` method to get the numeric value.

```js
var num = new Number(23.456);
console.log(typeof(num.valueOf())) //output: number
```